# Retrieve windows defender scan status on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, wmi-query

**Problem**: On windows 10 I query the WMI using C# at the namespace `Root\Microsoft\Windows\Defender` for the class `MSFT_MpComputerStatus` to get useful information about the computer antivirus status ([see this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/defender/msft-mpcomputerstatus)). This is because from windows 8.1 to the most recent Windows that namespace exists as it can be seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyGID.png)

```
...
private private const string WMIWindowsDefenderNameSpace = @"Root\Microsoft\Windows\Defender";
private const string MpComputerStatus = "MSFT_MpComputerStatus";
...
...
// And some lines later
var status QueryWMI(WMIWindowsDefenderNameSpace, MpComputerStatus);
```

However, things don't work that way on Windows 7 because as it can be seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rCYF.png) the namespace `Root\Microsoft\Windows\Defender` does not exist, therefore the above snippet will hand me an exception stating `"Invalid Namespace"`

**Question**: How do I programatically read the information equivalent to what is contained in class `MSFT_MpComputerStatus` if there's no such thing on up to Windows 7 ?

Comment: If there is nothing, then you can't read it. Maybe it is stored at a different place with a different name. I guess you have to research, what it is called on Windows 7?

Comment: Yeah, I've search with no success as of now. Thus this post.

Comment: Okay. Maybe asking that question in a Microsoft specific board helps? It's less of an code related question.

Comment: The `MSFT_MpComputerStatus` is present in the `ROOT\Microsoft\protectionManagement` namespace and declared in `"c:\Program Files\Windows Defender\ProtectionManagement.mof"` file.